# print JSON objects using perl

Tags: perl

I am new to perl and i had written below snippet of code to get the JSON objects from the data. But the input data has both hashes and arrays, So how do i get those values for "id" which is an array ?

```
  use strict;
  use warnings;
  use Data::Dumper;
  use JSON

 my $data = '{"total":325,"id": [78,234,737,1253,1459,1733,2166,2653,2855,3133,3414,3538,3729,3905,3991,4110,4160,4536,4692,4701]}';

 print Dumper($data);
 my @hash_ref = from_json($data);

 foreach my $hash_scalar (@hash_ref) {

    foreach (keys %{$hash_scalar}) {
        print "$_ => ${$hash_scalar}{$_}\n";
        }
    }
```

Output Getting

#

```
$VAR1 = '{"total":325,"id": 
[78,234,737,1253,1459,1733,2166,2653,2855,3133,3414,3538,3729,3905,3991,4110,4160,4536,4692,4701]}';
id => ARRAY(0x2afee4c)
total => 325
```

Comment: 1. The result of from_json when decoding a JSON string is a scalar, so assigning it to an array just results in a confusing array of one item. 2. The scalar returned in this case is a hash reference since that's what the overall JSON object correlates to in Perl. The value of the `id` key is a reference to an array. See [perlreftut](https://perldoc.pl/perlreftut).

Comment: You used Data::Dumper to print the JSON string, but it actually is not needed there, it's just a string. It would be more useful to print a debugging representation of the array reference, instead of printing the reference directly like you did. `print Dumper($hash_scalar->{$_});`

Comment: Tip: `${$hash_scalar}{$_}` is a lot hard to read than the equivalent `$hash_scalar->{$_}`

Comment: Printing `$VAR` with `x` from inside the Perl debugger would present more information on the result you've got.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `id` is a key in the hash reference you get back, and you want to grab its value, which is an array reference. You can either keep that as a reference or grab its elements right away:

```
#!perl
use v5.24;
use JSON qw(from_json);

my $data = '{"total":325,"id": [78,234,737]}';

my $json = from_json($data);

# get the hash key to get the hash value, which is an array reference
my $ids_array_ref = $json->{id};

# OR, use the postfix dereference to get the ids as a normal list
my @ids_array = $json->{id}->@*;

# OR, use the older circumfix notation (before Perl v5.24). These are all
# the same:
my @ids_array = @{ $json->{id} };
my @ids_array = @{ $ids_array_ref };
my @ids_array = @$ids_array_ref;
```

For example:

```
#!perl
use v5.24;
use JSON qw(from_json);

my $data = '{"total":325,"id": [78,234,737]}';

my $json = from_json($data);

foreach my $id ( $json->{id}->@* ) {
    say "Got id $id";
    }
```

This outputs:

```
Got id 78
Got id 234
Got id 737
```

But, you have to handle the other hash value types too. To decide how to print something, you have to check if it's a reference and what sort of reference it is (I ignore the other sorts here):

```
#!perl
use v5.24;
use JSON qw(from_json);

my $data = '{"total":325,"id": [78,234,737]}';

my $json = from_json($data);

foreach my $key ( keys $json->%* ) {
    print "$key: ";
    if( ref $json->{$key} eq 'ARRAY' ) {
        say join ' ', $json->{$key}->@*;
        }
    elsif( ref $json->{$key} ) { # all other reference types
        warn "I don't handle this yet"
        }
    else {
        say $json->{$key};
        }
    }
```

But, you might have deeper levels of nesting, so you'd need to think about that too if you want to output everything. If I know what keys I want, I don't try to go through everything in a general way. I go directly to want I want:

```
#!perl
use v5.24;
use JSON qw(from_json);

my $data = '{"total":325,"id": [78,234,737]}';

my $json = from_json($data);

say "id: ", join ' ', $json->{id}->@*;
say "total: ", $json->{total};
```

---

Your original code was doubly complicated. The result of `from_json` is the reference that represents the JSON data structure. That's a JSON object, which is what Perl calls a hash, so you get a hash reference back.

```
my $hash_ref = from_json( $data );
```

Your example almost worked because you got an array of one element, which is that hash reference. The other `foreach` then iterates over that one element. Get rid of that outer array and you get rid of the outer loop.

We cover references and data structures in [Intermediate Perl](https://www.intermediateperl.com), although the [perldsc](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html) is good too. We have a long examples of deeply-nested and recursive data structures.

If you're new, you may want to start with [Learning Perl](https://www.learning-perl.com), though.

Answer (score 0):

My Perl is getting rusty, but I think something like this should do the trick. You need to de-reference your array reference with another `@{...}` like `@{${$hash_scalar}{$_}}`.

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use JSON

my $data = '{"total":325,"id": [78,234,737,1253,1459,1733,2166,2653,2855,3133,3414,3538,3729,3905,3991,4110,4160,4536,4692,4701]}';

print Dumper($data);
my @hash_ref = from_json($data);

for my $hash_scalar (@hash_ref) {
    for my $key (keys(%{$hash_scalar})) {
        print("$key => @{${$hash_scalar}{$_}}\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use each to iterate hashes, the [most up to date docs](https://perldoc.pl/functions/each) explains the pitfalls.

Comment: Dereferencing the array reference with `@{}` may be what is needed, but only to access the whole array as a list or size. The appropriate operation should be used to work with the array reference depending what the program should do with it.

Comment: Corrected now. I did say that my Perl is rusty.

Comment: By trying to reuse the original code that has many problems, you've missed the run time errors that will stop the program. Remember to run your code before posting (coming from someone who's failed to do that any times too :)

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps following code will cover your question in more complete extent.

NOTE: I've added a hash in data block as bonus

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use JSON;
use Data::Dumper;

my $debug = 0;

my $data = '{ "total":325,
              "id": [78,234,737,1253,1459,1733,2166,2653,2855,3133,3414,3538,3729,3905,3991,4110,4160,4536,4692,4701],
              "person": {
                "first": "John",
                "last": "Smith", 
                "age": 27, 
                "occupation": "accountant",
                "wife": "Maria Smith",
                "son": "Alex Smith",
                "daughter": "Samantha Smith",
                "dog": "Sparky",
                "hobby": "photography"
               }
            }';

say Dumper($data) if $debug;

my $json = from_json($data);

say Dumper($json) if $debug;

while( my($k,$v) = each %{$json} ) {
    say "Key: $k";
    if( ref $v eq 'ARRAY' ) {
        say "\tValue is ARRAY";
        for ( @{$v} ) { say "\t\t[$_]" }
    } elsif( ref $v eq 'HASH' ) {
        say "\tValue is HASH";
        while( my($hk,$hv) = each %{$v} ) {
            say "\t\t$hk => $hv";
        }
    } else {
        say "\tValue: $v";
    }
}

say '-' x 40;
say 'Element with index 5 is ' . $json->{id}[5];
say 'Name of the son      is ' . $json->{person}{son};
say 'Name of the daughter is ' . $json->{person}{daughter};
```

Output

```
Key: person
        Value is HASH
                son => Alex Smith
                occupation => accountant
                daughter => Samantha Smith
                age => 27
                wife => Maria Smith
                dog => Sparky
                last => Smith
                first => John
                hobby => photography
Key: id
        Value is ARRAY
                [78]
                [234]
                [737]
                [1253]
                [1459]
                [1733]
                [2166]
                [2653]
                [2855]
                [3133]
                [3414]
                [3538]
                [3729]
                [3905]
                [3991]
                [4110]
                [4160]
                [4536]
                [4692]
                [4701]
Key: total
        Value: 325
----------------------------------------
Element with index 5 is 1733
Name of the son      is Alex Smith
Name of the daughter is Samantha Smith
```